# CNF SAT conversions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability

I am interested in reductions from 3-CNF boolean expressions to similar restricted forms. For example, I am interested in knowing how to reduce a 3-CNF formula to another 3-CNF formula where each variable appears in at most $b$ clauses. I observed this is used in MAX-SAT so I am interested in knowing such reductions. Is there a paper/book that contains descriptions of such forms and their properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feige's classical paper [A threshold of ln n for approximating set cover](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~feige/Approx/setcover.ps) shows that 3SAT-5 is NP-complete; this is the version of 3SAT in which each variable occurs *exactly* 5 times. The general trick here is to include clauses stating $a \leftrightarrow b$, thus allowing "duplication" of variables. If you're very careful, you can get to the symmetric situation considered by Feige.

(On the subject of set cover, recently [Dinur and Steurer](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1979v2.pdf) showed that it is NP-hard to approximate set cover better than $\ln n$, using a reduction of [Moshkovitz](https://people.csail.mit.edu/dmoshkov/papers/set-cover/set-cover.pdf). Feige's result relies on a stronger assumption.)

Comment: I am pretty new to the field of SAT solving, so do you know where can I find descriptions of various forms, possibly at one place? I've tried looking at Handbook of Satisfiability, but couldn't find it there. I guess it might be the case that this is just spread around as there are probably a lot of forms.

Comment: My guess is that this is too elementary to be discussed anywhere, though you can check Garey & Johnson or any other collection of NP-complete problems.